# Configuration of RStudio in University proxy network

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio

I'm using RStudio ver 3.3 .

I'm not a tech guy so it's a pain in the arse. Can anyone please help me with configuration of RStudio in proxy network. I've looked it up in google but they're talking about username and passwords which my university proxy does not have. My proxy host name is 10.3.100.207 and port is 8080 IP settings DHCP.

Thank you

P.S: Less technical terms will be appreciated :P but still answer anyway I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Have you see [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)? Note that passwords are not mandatory, as explained in the text.

Comment: RStudio Server: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#Server can be installed in one server and can be accessed from your network and includes administrative tools.